# Probabilidad con Sipy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy

Intento resolver con Scipy, el siguiente problema de cálculo de probabilidades.

Un alumno contesta las 70 preguntas de un exámen de matemáticas, elegidas al azar. Si cada pregunta tiene 5 alternativas y sólo una de éstas es correcta, entonces ¿Cuál es la probabilidad de que tenga la puntuación máxima?

Hay una alternativa correcta de un total de cinco en cada pregunta. Por lo tanto, la probabilidad de acertar una pregunta es una de cinco, es decir, P(x = 1) = 1/5

Para obtener el puntaje máximo se deben acertar las 70 preguntas, independientes entre sí. Por lo tanto, la probabilidad pedida es:

P(x = 70) =(1/5) ^70

Para el cálculo con scipy desarrollo el código siguiente.

```
from scipy.stats import binom

# Definir los parámetros del experimento
num_preguntas = 6
prob_exito = 0.5

# Crear una distribución binomial
distribucion = binom(num_preguntas, prob_exito)

# Calcular la probabilidad de obtener exactamente 5 éxitos (respuestas correctas) en las últimas cinco preguntas
probabilidad_correctas = distribucion.pmf(5)

# Imprimir el resultado
print("La probabilidad de contestar correctamente las cinco últimas preguntas es:", probabilidad_correctas)
```

Uutilizamos la distribución binomial. En este caso, consideramos un éxito seleccionar la respuesta correcta y una probabilidad de éxito en cada pregunta de 1/5.

No devuelve el valor correcto, acorde con el resultado obtenido en la introducción al problema. ¿Cuál es la causa?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Buen día, el único problema que tiene tu código es que `1/5` no es `0.5` sino `0.2`. Si el número de preguntas lo configuras como `70`, el argumento `k` del método `pmf` también `70` que serían 70 respuestas correctas de 70 preguntas y `prob_exito = 0.2` vas a obtener el resultado correcto que sería `1.18059162071742e-49`. Es decir, el código funciona correctamente, lo que está mal es el resultado que esperas obtener de acuerdo a los parámetros que ingresas.

Comment: Si tienes 6 preguntas con 2 opciones cada una, es decir `prob_exito = 0.5` como lo configuraste y obtienes 5 respuestas correctas, es decir `k = 5` el resultado es  `0.09375000000000003` tal como lo devuelve tu código.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la explicación de  [HeytalePazguato](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/171630/heytalepazguato)    , el código correcto quedaría así:

```
from scipy.stats import binom

# Definir los parámetros del experimento
num_preguntas = 70
prob_exito = 1/5

# Crear una distribución binomial
distribucion = binom(num_preguntas, prob_exito)

# Calcular la probabilidad de obtener la puntuación máxima
probabilidad_maxima = distribucion.pmf(num_preguntas)

# Imprimir el resultado
print("La probabilidad de obtener la puntuación máxima es:", probabilidad_maxima)
```